# Need to play audio in java

Tags: java, user-interface

How do I play a sound during a specific event in Java?

I need to make an audio cue for picking up a coin

Here's my code:

```
private void movePlayer(int dRow, int dColumn) {
        
        //
        maze[player.getRow()][player.getColumn()].setIcon(PATH);
        
        //
        if (maze[player.getRow()+dRow][player.getColumn()+dColumn].getIcon() == COIN) {
            numCoinsCollected++;
            scoreLabel.setText(Integer.toString(numCoinsCollected));    
        }
        
        //
        player.move(dRow, dColumn);
        maze[player.getRow()][player.getColumn()].setIcon(player.getIcon());
        
        //
        if (numCoinsCollected == NUM_COINS) {
            gameTimer.stop();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "WINNER!");
        }
    }
```

I tried `java.applet.*;` but it's outdated

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [javax.sound.sampled](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/package-summary.html) package.
Additionally, this Oracle forum post [Example: Code to generate audio tone](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/example-code-to-generate-audio-tone-8529)

I was able to compile a basic sound after some searching.

```java
void sound() throws LineUnavailableException {
    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(44100, 8, 1, true, false);
    SourceDataLine dataline = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(format);
    dataline.open();
    dataline.start();
    double angle;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
    for (int index = 0; index < 44100; index++) {
        angle = index / (44100 / 440f) * 2 * Math.PI;
        buffer[0] = (byte) (Math.sin(angle) * 100);
        dataline.write(buffer, 0, 1);
    }
    dataline.drain();
    dataline.stop();
}
```